# Adding a List Box

Tags: javascript, html

AM using 2 buttons in my Page. Add and Remove
If I press Add, a row of text box and a list box should be added. 
Remove is used to Undo the Previous operation.

The code I have used is,

```
var cellRight = row.insertCell(5);

var el = document.createElement('input');

el.setAttribute('type', 'text');

el.setAttribute('name', 'txtRow');

el.setAttribute('size', '15');

cellRight.appendChild(el);
```

This works well if I use only text box. To add a List box

```
var cellRight = row.insertCell(6);

var el = document.createElement('input');

el.setAttribute('type', 'select');

el.setAttribute('size', '15');

el.setAttribute('method','onclick');

cellRight.appendChild(el);
```

I wrote this code, but when I press the "Add" button, only Text Boxes instead of list boxes.
Is my code correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `<input type="select">`. You need to create a `select` element and add `option` sub-elements.

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
var el = document.createElement('select');
el.setAttribute('name', 'txtRow');
el.setAttribute('size', '15');

var label = document.createTextNode('item1label');
var opt = document.createElement('option'); 
opt.setAttribute('value', 'item1value');
opt.appendChild(label);
el.appendChild(opt);

cellRight.appendChild(el);
```

Beware, dry-coded, ymmv.

Comment: Also, worth mentioning that this would be simpler with a JS library, in case you've not come across one. For example, one of: jQuery, Prototype, MooTools, etc.